# Django. Get id of ForeignKey object in CreateView

Tags: python, django, create-view, django-class-based-views

I study the CBV in django. 
I want a user can upload images to a certain card of an apartment.
So The model was created:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    photo_path = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Фотография')
    photo_user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Агент, добавивший фото')
    photo_flat = models.ForeignKey(Flat, verbose_name='Квартира')
    photo_description = models.CharField(verbose_name='Описание', max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
```

The initial data of the form are photo_user and the photo_flat.
When I try to save one or multiple pictures through a form on the page I've got `AttributeError`.

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

My ModelForm looks like this:

```
class PhotoUploadModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ['photo_path','photo_user','photo_flat','photo_description'
```

My CreateView:

```
class PhotoUploadView(CreateView):
    form_class = PhotoUploadModelForm
    def get_initial(self):
        return {'photo_user': self.request.user,
                'photo_flat': self.object.pk
                }
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('ha:flatdetail')
```

and my urls.py

```
url(r'^dev/flat/(?P<flat_id>[0-9]+)/$', views_dev.flat_ajax, name='flatdetail'),
url(r'^dev/photo-update/$', views_dev.PhotoUploadView.as_view(), name='image-update')
```

I understand the error but has not enough skills to handle it. am I correct that self.object.pk would be the id of the picture but not the apartment?
Can I get the id of the apartment?

Comment: @Pythonista, I think that I try to do something silly, 
If i want to pass flat.id to `photo_flat` maybe I should  include `flat = get_object_or_404(Flat)` in `def get_initial(self)`? But it returns whole list of flats that I have. How can I pass certain id? Like this: `flat = get_object_or_404(Flat, pk=flat_id)`? But it doesn't work because `get_initial` doesn't have `flat_id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're misinterpreting the error, but that is partly because what you're doing doesn't make a lot of sense.

`self.object` can only refer to the object that this view is concerned with, which in this case is the Photo; but of course that photo doesn't exist yet when you do `get_initial`, because it hasn't been created. It seems that you want to use the ID of a specific Flat object; in which case you would need to pass that ID to the view, ie via the URL. You do this already in your `flat_ajax` view; you should do exactly the same thing here, and then you will be able to reference the ID via `self.kwargs['flat_id']`.

Note that `get_initial` isn't really the best place to be doing this, anyway. The User and the Flat object are not values that you want to pass to the form so that they populate fields initially but let the user change them; they are values you want to automatically associate with the object on save. So, this should really be done in `form_valid`, as shown in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user):

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.photo_user = self.request.user
    form.instance.photo_flat_id = self.kwargs['flat_id']
    return super(PhotoUploadView, self).form_valid(form)
```

If you do it this way, you should remove `photo_user` and `photo_flat` from the fields listed in the form.